# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Problem with Request encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

**Hello!**

There is a controller and an action which receives one param through GET, approximately here so:

www.site.com/controller/action/?query=параметр <- Russian word

**Problem:**

Example 1: www.site.com/controller/action/?query=Пример <- Russian word

Example 2: www.site.com/controller/action/?query=Example

Reading param:

```
var param = Request.QueryString["query"];
```

**Result 1:**

```
  param = "������"
```

The data from debugger:

```
Request.RawUrl = "/controller/action/?q=%CF%F0%E8%EC%E5%F0"
QueryString = {q=%ufffd%ufffd%ufffd%ufffd%ufffd%ufffd}
```

**Result 2:**

```
param = "Example"
```

The data from debugger:

```
Request. RawUrl = "/controller/action/?q=Example"
QueryString = {q=Example}
```

ContentEncoding is setted into UTF-8.

```
Web.config:
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"
           fileEncoding="utf-8" />
```

**Question:**
How can i correctly get param with russian word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["q"], Encoding.Default)
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use Russian words in URI (и даже не стоит пробовать). You should encode them.

[RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html): Uniform Resource Locators (URL) specification

..Only alphanumerics [0-9a-zA-Z], the special characters "$-_.+!*'()," [not including the quotes - ed], and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

If your users going to enter urls themselves in russian - (for searching) you can try [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) Request.Url

Comment: Thank you very much!

UrlDecode works. HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["q"], Encoding.Default);

But very strange, that Encoding.Default is win-1251. I for some reason thought that Win7 fully uses Unicode :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) the querystring values.