# How to read the value of the parameter url in Russian in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

For example, [http://example.com?name=Имя](http://example.com?name=%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F) in QueryString is some kind of hieroglyphs. This problem occurs only when you run the application in Linux, Windows is OK.

```
public IActionResult Index(string name)
{
    // name == "РёРјСЏ"
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem using methods from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577376/how-to-read-values-from-the-querystring-with-asp-net-core)?

Comment: Try to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488977/asp-net-mvc-2-problem-with-request-encoding). Looks like similar problem

Comment: This problem occurs only when you run the application in Linux, Windows is OK

Comment: IActionResult Index(string name) { // name == "РёРјСЏ"}